# Error "UnsatisfiedDependencyException" up Java Spring JDBC application - hosting

Tags: java, spring-boot, hosting, spring-jdbc

I don't have much experience with hosting, I have a local test app. But when I generated the Jar and when trying to go up in hosting (Integrator with CPanel). I get the following error that I couldn't identify the cause:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)

13:36:58.105 [main] INFO br.com.example.luckytips.LuckytipsApplication - Starting LuckytipsApplication using Java 13.0.2 on server41.integrator.com.br with PID 2364652 (/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar started by willis1857 in /home/willis1857)
13:36:58.109 [main] DEBUG br.com.example.luckytips.LuckytipsApplication - Running with Spring Boot, Spring
13:36:58.142 [main] INFO br.com.example.luckytips.LuckytipsApplication - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
13:36:58.143 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class br.com.example.luckytips.LuckytipsApplication
13:36:58.334 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@ba57f1b2
13:36:58.354 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
13:36:58.494 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: URL [jar:file:/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar!/br/com/example/luckytips/repository/DoubleRepository.class]
13:36:58.508 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar!/br/com/example/luckytips/config/WebSocketConfig.class]
13:36:58.513 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar!/br/com/example/luckytips/config/MyDsConfig.class]
13:36:58.516 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar!/br/com/example/luckytips/config/CorsFilter.class]
13:36:58.544 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar!/br/com/example/luckytips/controller/WsController.class]
13:36:58.547 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar!/br/com/example/luckytips/controller/LuckyRestController.class]
13:36:58.566 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar!/br/com/example/luckytips/service/ServiceDoubleBlz.class]
13:36:58.580 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar!/br/com/example/luckytips/service/RecordCherckerService.class]
13:37:01.094 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
13:37:01.323 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages'
13:37:01.327 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages - @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'br.com.example.luckytips'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
13:37:01.338 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Scanning for JPA repositories in packages br.com.example.luckytips.
13:37:01.609 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/willis1857/appservers/standalone/luckytips.jar!/br/com/example/luckytips/repository/DoubleRepository.class]
13:37:02.181 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 818 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
13:37:03.149 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer'
13:37:03.162 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'webSocketScopeConfigurer'
13:37:03.169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer$DependsOnDatabaseInitializationPostProcessor'
13:37:03.169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'emBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor'
13:37:03.220 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
13:37:03.221 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'preserveErrorControllerTargetClassPostProcessor'
13:37:03.224 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
13:37:03.224 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory'
13:37:03.257 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
13:37:03.263 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
13:37:03.268 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
13:37:03.269 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
13:37:03.269 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinder'
13:37:03.269 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinderFactory'
13:37:03.281 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
13:37:03.282 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration'
13:37:03.330 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'
13:37:03.437 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor'
13:37:03.522 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' via factory method to bean named 'environment'
13:37:03.528 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'webServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor'
13:37:03.529 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'errorPageRegistrarBeanPostProcessor'
13:37:03.530 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor'
13:37:03.535 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
13:37:03.536 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration'
13:37:03.804 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionAttributeSource'
13:37:03.840 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'transactionInterceptor'
13:37:03.841 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'transactionInterceptor' via factory method to bean named 'transactionAttributeSource'
13:37:03.860 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' via factory method to bean named 'transactionAttributeSource'
13:37:03.861 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' via factory method to bean named 'transactionInterceptor'
13:37:03.974 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'entityManagerFactory'
13:37:03.975 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration'
13:37:03.977 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
13:37:03.977 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'myDsConfig'
13:37:03.986 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties'
13:37:04.022 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.BoundConfigurationProperties'
13:37:04.086 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'dataSource' via factory method to bean named 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties'
13:37:04.130 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException...
13:37:04.151 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [br/com/example/luckytips/config/MyDsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested ex...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$129/0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$129/0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at br.com.example.luckytips.LuckytipsApplication.main(LuckytipsApplication.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [br/com/example/luckytips/config/MyDsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSo...
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$129/0000000000000000.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:182)
    at br.com.example.luckytips.config.MyDsConfig.dataSource(MyDsConfig.java:22)
    at br.com.example.luckytips.config.MyDsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a28275e.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>)
    at br.com.example.luckytips.config.MyDsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a28275e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$970e76b8.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at br.com.example.luckytips.config.MyDsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a28275e.dataSource(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

**Application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
]spring.mvc.locale=pt_BR
logging.file.max-size=3MB
logging.file.name=${logging.file.path}/luckytips.log
logging.file.path=/home/willis1857/appservers/private/springboot/logs/
logging.pattern.dateformat=dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss
logging.pattern.file=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%
logging.level.root=INFO
server.port=${port:10661}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'br.com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '13'

configurations {
    provided
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main { compileClasspath += configurations.provided }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.7.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.7.4'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-websocket
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-websocket:5.3.23'
    implementation  'org.springframework:spring-messaging'

    implementation 'org.webjars:webjars-locator-core'
    implementation 'org.webjars:sockjs-client:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.webjars:stomp-websocket:2.3.3'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.7'
    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:3.1.1-1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket"

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Location everything works fine. Any hints as to what the problem could be.

Comment: We need the full exception stacktrace, because that contains the actual error that causes Spring to fail to instantiate the bean.

Comment: Sorry...Post Updated

Comment: Make sure that `org.postgresql:postgresql` is available at runtime - e.g. using `--classpath`/`--module-path` or by changing its scope to `implementation`.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps of @dan1st but it didn't work, apparently a problem with the driver in the hosting. I chose to use the standard Apache on the hosting server with JDBC embedded instead of the provided SpringBoot deploy and it worked.